# How can I ask journalctl to show records for all units except one?

Tags: logging, systemd, journalctl

`journalctl -u ssh` prints all records associated with the ssh unit. But how can I get all records *not* associated with the ssh unit? Things that don't work: `journalctl -u '!ssh'`; `journalctl '!_SYSTEMD_UNIT=ssh'`; `journalctl '_SYSTEMD_UNIT!=ssh'`. Documentation doesn't suggest that this is possible, but I'm still hopeful. ;-)

Comment: What's wrong with `grep -v sshd`? Or more refined, `grep -v "$(hostname) sshd\["`.

Comment: That's similar to what I'm doing currently, but I'd prefer a solution that's independent of the journalctl output format. My current kludge is: `journalctl -f | awk '$5 !~ /sshd\[[0-9]+\]:/ { print }'`.